# Controlling Location of Popover

Tags: ipad, ios5, popover

I have an Add UIButton on my MainViewController that loads a popover. Even though the Add button is located on the far right, I would like the popover to be centered when loaded. The only view for the iPad app (iOS 5.1) will be landscape. I removed the direction arrows.

I've tried @property (nonatomic, readwrite) UIEdgeInsets popoverLayoutMargins; but I cannot figure out how to code with it.

I've also come across presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)] with no luck.

I can include code if necessary.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code centers the popover on the x axis at the top of the screen.  If you also want to center it on the y axis, use self.view.frame.height/2 as the second parameter in CGRectMake.

```
    [_myPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 ,0,1,1)
                                     inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
```